# How can I install Jgrasp on Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: ide, 22.10

I was trying to use the file linking method but when I right click my mouse there was no "link to file" option as indicated in a certain tutorial. I was hoping there was any other method I could use which would be really helpful.
This is the link to that tutorial [https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/install-jgrasp-ubuntu-with-code-examples.html#:~:text=Go%20to%20jgrasp.org%20download,%2Dget%20install%20lsb%2Dcore](https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/install-jgrasp-ubuntu-with-code-examples.html#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20jgrasp.org%20download,%2Dget%20install%20lsb%2Dcore).

Comment: What tutorial? Please add the link to the question with edit not as a comment.

Comment: As I look at that link the first thing it tells you to do is install a version of Java from 2006. That is not going to work on Ubuntu 22.10 unless you create a docker container and install an OS that will support this. Unless this is something you want to do I do not think you will be installing this app.